# Highstocks How to change the font of the buttons of the range selecotor

Tags: highcharts

I built a Highstock graph and want to change the font of the buttons. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/ofwmuy7r/1/)

```
buttonTheme: {
              fill: '#0065b3',
              padding: 10,
              width: 60,
              r: '5',
              style: {
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins'
                     },
              states: {
                    hover: {
                          style: {
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontWeight: 'bold'
                                }                           
                          },
                    select: {
                          style: {
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins'
                                  }
                             }
                      }
                      },
```

The font of the selected button is correct but the others are not. After hovering over them they get the correct font and keep it. When you reload the graphic the font is lost again. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the CSS properties to set it as workaround:

```
.highcharts-range-selector-buttons {
    font-family: Poppins !important;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qfp1erjv/